# Bootstrap-UI Popover not showing up

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I have a problem with the popover directive from Bootstrap-UI(http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

For some reason the popover does not show up.
I have an ng-if which condition gets true if the user do some action, and that's when the popover is added to an element in some cell in a table.

I tried without the ng-if using the popover choice and it does show up. So it must be something with the combination of the ng-if and the popover directive.

```
<td>
  <p ng-if="transaction.resolution == 'INCORRECT_DATA'" class="error-text" popover="{{transaction.reasons}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="top" popover-popup-delay="500">{{transaction.amount * transaction.currency.rate | number: 2}}</p>
  <p ng-if="transaction.resolution != 'INCORRECT_DATA'" class="info-text">{{transaction.amount * transaction.currency.rate | number: 2}}</p>
</td>
```

Comment: Please place more code or create `jsfiddle`..